# WCF POST Service With List<Object> as Parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF Service. I created a POST method that contain multiple parameters as an object without problem, like :

```
 public class BudgetTransactionRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string transaction_code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double? amount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime request_date { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string request_status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string owner { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string opportunity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string project { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string application_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string category { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string claim_status { get; set; }
}
```

My POST method can run well. But now, i need to pass multiple object parameter like this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mlpt-web.com/CRM/services")]
    public class CreateBudget
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string pr_code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<BudgetTransactionRequest> transactions { get; set; } 

    }
```

On the server side, how can i read every single parameters of object inside the list ? I need to get every parameters inside the object so i can run the other process.

I tried:

```
 public string CreateBudget(CreateBudget cbreq)
        {if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbreq.pr_code))
            {
                List<BudgetTransactionRequest> bt = new List<BudgetTransactionRequest>();
                for (int i = 0; i < bt.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bt[i].transaction_code))
                        {
                            budgettrx["new_name"] = bt[i].transaction_code;
                        }
                        _service.Create(budgettrx);
                    }
                }

            }
            return "Done";
        }
```

But i m not sure this gonna be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for each loop go loop through the list and get the objects inside of it.

```
foreach (var myObj in yourList) {

}
```

Comment: Like this ? 
`foreach (var bt in cbreq.transactions)
                {
                    string tr = bt.transaction_code; 
                }`

Comment: yeah, did you try

Comment: Oke, thanks  for your advice. 
I need to write client code so i knew that the code is work.